# How to filter javascript array using substring search for key and value pair

Tags: javascript, node.js

in the below array i want to filter out records, that match the substring "11/2022" for key StartTime

```
[
  {
    StartTime: '17/10/2022 14:45',
    Duration: '000:00:44:32',
  },
  {
    StartTime: '17/11/2022 14:45',
    Duration: '000:00:44:30',
 
  },
  {
    StartTime: '18/11/2022 14:45',
    Duration: '000:00:44:30',
 
  },  
   {
    StartTime: '17/12/2022 14:45',
    Duration: '000:00:44:30',
 
  }
]
```

expected output:

```
[
   {
    StartTime: '17/11/2022 14:45',
    Duration: '000:00:44:30',
 
  },
   {
    StartTime: '18/11/2022 14:45',
    Duration: '000:00:44:30',
 
  }
   
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the includes function like this

```
[
    { StartTime: "17/10/2022 14:45", Duration: "000:00:44:32" },
    { StartTime: "17/11/2022 14:45", Duration: "000:00:44:30" },
    { StartTime: "18/11/2022 14:45", Duration: "000:00:44:30" },
    { StartTime: "17/12/2022 14:45", Duration: "000:00:44:30" },
  ].filter((item) => item.StartTime.includes("11/2022"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter() to loop through the array of objects, and for each object item, check whether the StartTime includes() any of the search keyword substring.

```js
const array = [{
    StartTime: '17/10/2022 14:45',
    Duration: '000:00:44:32',
  }, {
    StartTime: '17/11/2022 14:45',
    Duration: '000:00:44:30',

  }, {
    StartTime: '18/11/2022 14:45',
    Duration: '000:00:44:30',

  },
  {
    StartTime: '17/12/2022 14:45',
    Duration: '000:00:44:30',

  }
];

const searchKey = '11/2022';
const filteredArray = array.filter(item => item.StartTime.includes(searchKey));

console.log(filteredArray);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Just using `Array.filter()` can do it

```js
let data = [
  {
    StartTime: '17/10/2022 14:45',
    Duration: '000:00:44:32',
  },
  {
    StartTime: '17/11/2022 14:45',
    Duration: '000:00:44:30',
 
  },
  {
    StartTime: '18/11/2022 14:45',
    Duration: '000:00:44:30',
 
  },  
   {
    StartTime: '17/12/2022 14:45',
    Duration: '000:00:44:30',
 
  }
]

let result = data.filter(d => d.StartTime.includes('/11/2022'))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter() and regular expressions to check if substring in your string, also regular exp provides a lot of useful options so they may help you in future

```
const arr = [
    { StartTime: '17/10/2022 14:45', Duration: '000:00:44:32', }, 
    { StartTime: '17/11/2022 14:45', Duration: '000:00:44:30', }, 
    { StartTime: '18/11/2022 14:45', Duration: '000:00:44:30', },
    { StartTime: '17/12/2022 14:45', Duration: '000:00:44:30',}
]

const newArr = arr.filter(elem => elem.StartTime.match("11/2022"))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.filter()` and `.includes()`:

```js
const input = [
    { StartTime: '17/10/2022 14:45', Duration: '000:00:44:32', },
    { StartTime: '17/11/2022 14:45', Duration: '000:00:44:30', },
    { StartTime: '18/11/2022 14:45', Duration: '000:00:44:30', },
    { StartTime: '17/12/2022 14:45', Duration: '000:00:44:30', }
];

const result = input.filter(element => {
    return element.StartTime.includes("11/2022");
});

console.log(result);
```